# Fill but have a minimum size and make scrollbars working in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

I have a Form, inside the Form there is a Panel.

I would like the Panel to Fill the Form, but only if the Form is bigger then a minimum size.

Till this point it is already working.

When the Form is smaller then the Panel, I would like to have scrollbars. This is not working.

I set the AutoScroll in the form. The scrollbars working only if the Panel has a fixed size and the Form is smaller. If I set the Panel to Fill the form and set the minimum size, the scrollbars not appearing.

The following code snippet is from InitializeComponent of the Form

```
this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.panel1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 250);
this.AutoScroll = true;
```

In the picture you can see that the Panel is bigger then the Form, but there is no scrollbar.

[image]

Comment: Can you post what code you are using so far? Sounds like maybe the panel is shrinking with the form perhaps.

Comment: @JoshuaHysong I added some more information

Comment: You have to set "AutoScrollMinSize".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to set the forms AutoScrollMinSize property

```
this.AutoScroll = true;
this.AutoScrollMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 250);
```

Make this the same as your panels minimum size and the scrollbars will appear as desired only when the form is smaller than the panel.